# In what sense can a "manned model" boat handle identically to a much larger boat?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, scaling

A [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/M5cyq-XDZcM?t=1m22s)(relevant part is 1:24 - 1:46) suggests that if you take an oil tanker, scale it down 25 times, and give it an engine with 0.4 horsepower, "they behave exactly like a [larger] ship".

What does this mean, quantitatively? What is the power of the oil tanker being simulated? What is its mass?

Does the statement mean that the model and full ships have the same [Froude number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Froude_number) when operating at the same fraction of their power? If so, would boats of different size and the same Froude number have, for example, different rolling oscillation frequencies? Would they have the same turning radius relative to the size of the ship? Which aspects of operating a boat can be made the same for a toy model, and which cannot?

Comment: A have a vague memory that naval architects don't trust scale models when the scale is more extreme than 3:1.

Comment: You can make any aspect you like "the same". The problem is that you can't make *all* the relevant parameters "the same" at the same time. - for example the Froude number + viscous effects + the surface roughness of the scale model + etc...

Comment: @alephzero That should be an answer.